# How do we come know that vimeo has processed the uploaded video?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Once the video has been uplaoded to vimeo, how do i know that processing has been completed through API. So that i can embed the video into Iframe?

Answer (score 6):

The API representation of a video contains a field, `status`. This field will contain a string representing the status of the video. It can be one of the following

- available
- uploading
- transcoding
- quota_exceeded (can not play because the quota was exceeded before uploading this video)
- uploading_error
- transcoding_error

So if you request `https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos`, each video will contain the `status` field with one of the above values.

Comment: @Dashron Where do you get the list of possible values from? I've searched all over the API documentation, looking for detailed description of their various responses, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Here is a more full list: https://github.com/vimeo/mill/issues/75#issuecomment-438277167. Can't find any official documentation either though.

Answer (score 0):

Send a **HEAD** request to the `{upload.upload_link}` URL in the returned payload.

and you set these headers

```
Tus-Resumable: 1.0.0
Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4
```

Find below link to there documentation usage.

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#resumable-approach

> The response returns the HTTP 200 status code and the Upload-Length and Upload-Offset headers, among others. Determine the completeness of the upload by comparing the values of Upload-Length and Upload-Offset:

```
If Upload-Length and Upload-Offset are equal, we've received the entire video file.
If Upload-Length is larger than Upload-Offset, we haven't.
```